# TextView not printing after entry into edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this code in my `MainActivity.java` file, but when any value is typed into the edit text and the button is pressed, the related string does not print. How can I make it so that when the button is pressed, a certain text displays based on the string entered in the edit text slot?

```java
public void ShowAge(View view){

        EditText entered = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.typehere);
        TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        if(entered.getText().toString() == "Dog"){
            value.setText(R.string.dog);
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            value.setTypeface(typeFace);}
        else if(entered.getText().toString() == "Cat"){
            value.setText(R.string.cat);
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            value.setTypeface(typeFace);}
        else if(entered.getText().toString() == "Meal"){
            value.setText(R.string.meal);
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            value.setTypeface(typeFace);}
        else if(entered.getText().toString() == "Chocolate"){
            value.setText(R.string.chocolate);
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            value.setTypeface(typeFace);}
        else if(entered.getText().toString() == "Froyo"){
            value.setText(R.string.froyo);
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            value.setTypeface(typeFace);}
        }
```

Comment: try to use `equalsignorecase` for comparing Strings instead of `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [String.equals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare Strings. This will compare the characters in the String. The equals operator (`==`) compares the memory location, which is different.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 entered.getText().toString().equals("Some String")  {...
```

instead of

```
entered.getText().toString() == "Some String" {...
```

Always when you compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the above answers you should use String.equals() or String.equalsIgnoreCase() if you want to compare case insensitive.

Consider also you using [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to monitor the text entered in your EditText:

Ex:

```
    ...
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

        if (s == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim())) {
           return;
        }
        String enteredText = s.toString();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(enteredText)){
            return;
        }
        int resString = -1;
        String font = "font.ttf";
        if(enteredText.equals("Dog")){
            resString = R.string.dog;
        }
        else if(enteredText.equals("Cat")){
            resString = R.string.cat;
        }
        else if(enteredText.equals("Meal")){
           resString = R.string.meal;
        }
        else if(enteredText.equals("Chocolate")){
            resString = R.string.chocolate;
        }
        else if(enteredText..equals("Froyo")){
            resString = R.string.froyo;
        }

        if(resString>0){
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), font);
            value.setText(R.string.froyo);
            value.setTypeface(typeFace);
        }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
 if(entered.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Dog"))